# How to adjust HTML when website is in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, web

I have a Wordpress theme for a new website. I want to make some HTML adjustments but I realized that the website has only PHP scripts and of course the CSS file. For instance, I need to adjust the website name but cannot find H1 tags. I do not have any PHP knowledge. Please advice. Many thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCAO6.jpg)

Comment: usually the h1 tags will be populated by the page/post name, try editing the relevant item in those sections, but because of how general the question is, it will likely be closed I'm afraid.

Comment: the PHP files generate the html at some point,so if you open header.php you can search for the h1 if you want to change it for a h2 or something, if you want to edit the title itself, it is very likely there is a field somewhere to change it without changing the theme itself

Comment: Adjusting Wordpress themes is not really something a PHP novice should be doing. Worpress is driven by PHP. Themes have specific rules and expectations. You don't want to go breaking things.  You'll want to get up to speed with PHP if you really want to go down this path. As for chaning the Website name , this is normally not encompassed in the them but is more a token that is replaced from a setting in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is a bit different from vanilla PHP instead of echoing out HTML with the title:

```
<?php echo "<h1>The Title</h1>";  ?>
```

It uses a function/hook called `wp_title();` that you can find in `header.php`.
But to modify it you would have to in to `functions.php` and edit the function and for that you need some basic PHP knowledge.

Here is some documentation on the `wp_title()` function/hook.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<div>html here</div>";  ?>
```

You can as many php chunks as you want
example :

```
<?php echo "<h1>html here</h2>";  ?>



<?php echo "<span>html here</span>";  ?>
```